# RestKit: setBaseURL causes memory leaks

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, restkit

I am trying to get some info from the web by using RestKit.
Here is my code:

```
(void)getTestData:(NSString *)baseURL
{
    [[RKClient sharedClient] setBaseURL:baseURL];
    [[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/TestData" delegate:self];
}
```

But I find that when I use "setBaseURL", the memory leaks.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: If I annotate the setBaseURL row, there are no memory leaks. So I doubt if the setBaseURL method causes memory leak. And in my application, I need to use different URLs...
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use clientWithBaseURL metod when you init your application :

```
RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:@"http://restkit.org"];
```

But if you need to use several URL, this will not help you.

If you use only one URL, don't set URL il all methods used for GET/POST... data but just in application init with clientWithBaseURL.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I have used clientWithBaseURL metod when init my application. But in my application, I need to use different URLs. So I'm confused about this problem. Are there any better ways?
Thank you again!

Comment: Try to use "Instrument" to see witch object caused the memory leak. Can you show us your code when you call metod : -(void)getTestData:(NSString *)baseURL; ?

Comment: Another solution, With clientWithBaseURL you create new RKClient instance, and after use setSharedClient method for replace current shared instance of RKClient, thix method release previous instance.

Comment: I solved this problem by adding the release of the _hostName attribute in the method of initWithHostName in the RKReachabilityObserver.m file. I'm not sure if it is right, but indeed there are no leaks now. Thanks!